# Disadvantage of 3rd order vs 2nd order digital PLL with high C/N0?

Tags: stability, pll

I tried to determine the best choice between an aided 2nd order and an unaided 3rd order carrier digital PLL in a context where the \$C/N_0\$ is very high. From all aspects, the 3rd order loop seems better (except the computational complexity, but this does not matter in my case), thus I am afraid that I am missing something.

Here is a summary of the parameters impacted by the loop order based on my understanding:

1. Stability: The product of the loop bandwidth \$B_n\$ and integration time \$T\$ should be lower than a threshold, and the threshold is higher for the 3rd order loop than the 2nd order loop by a factor 1.4, Table 8.24 from [1]. ⇒ A 3rd order loop can have a loop bandwidth 1.4 times higher for a same integration time.
2. Allan variance: The formula giving the Allan deviation induced phased error is better for a second order loop (factor of 144 vs 160, Eqs. (8-76) & (8-77) from [1]), but since a 3rd order loop can have a higher loop bandwidth and the Allan variance induced error is inversely proportional to the loop bandwidth, the error can be lower with a 3rd order loop.
3. Dynamic stress: the error is proportional to \$\frac{d^2r/dt^2}{B_n^2}\$ for a 2nd order loop, and to \$\frac{d^3r/dt^3}{B_n^3}\$ for a 3rd order loop, where \$d^nr/dt^n\$ is the \$n\$th derivative of the range (Eqs. (8-78) & (8-79) from [1]). Therefore, the error should be lower for a 3rd order loop, even maybe compared to an unaided 2nd order loop, especially if the loop bandwidth is very high.

From that, I see that an unaided 3rd order loop is better than an aided 2nd order loop, with the plan to use a high loop bandwidth (> 100 Hz).
In a normal context, the drawback is that a higher loop bandwidth means a higher thermal noise error. But in my case the \$C/N_0\$ is so high that this error is negligible, and the dominant errors are the Allan variance and Dynamic stress.

I am missing something important, or does this makes sense?

[1] Kaplan, Hegarty, editors, Understanding GPS/GNSS: Principles and Applications, Chapter 8, P. W. Ward, author, “GNSS receivers”, Artech House, 3rd Edition, 2018.